# Is the old `setX` value from `useState` still valid after the state is updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say that we use the React hook `useState` and then store `setX` within a closure that keeps the reference around even after `setX` is called from another place. Is the original `setX` still valid to use?

Example:

```js
const [x, setX] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  // this timeout runs `setX` first
  setTimeout(() => setX(1), 500);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // this `setX` will be called after a new `setX` is returned
  // after the re-render caused by the first `setX`
  setTimeout(() => setX(2), 1000);
}, []);
```

While capturing the old version of `x` could clearly cause issues, and there are ways to fix that (`setX(a => a + 1)` or `useContext`), this question is aimed purely at `setX` and what it's lifespan is.

Is it possible that `useState` will return the same setter on each call? Or does it always return a new one? Are all of the returned setters valid, even after the value has changed?

Note that this is not necessarily a question about how this works in the current implementation, as that is something that one can trivially check. The question is how this should work, and more importantly how it should be used, and what is the expectation the developer can have about `setX`, its lifetime, and usage.

Comment: `Is it possible that useState will return the same setter on each call?` You add setX to the effect dependencies and see that it still only runs on mount therefor it doesn't change. The liner knows this and doesn't warn you about missing dependency for setX.

Comment: `setX` is a `const` that lives as long as that controller instance does so not really clear where your confusion is

Comment: In other words...calling setX does not replace that const with a new instance of setX

Comment: @HMR adding `setX` to the dependencies causes a different behavior, I don't want to re-run the effect when `setX` changes ... I'd argue that there are many times where you don't want to specify the dependency if the effect is only meant to run as in `componentDidMount`

@charlietfl I think you misunderstood my question. The component gets re-rendered when the first effect calls `setX`, the whole scope gets deallocated, and a new call to `useState` returns a possibly new `setX`, this has nothing to do with `const`

Comment: @JakubArnold `adding setX to the dependencies causes a different behavior`: No it doesn't because setX never changes, repeating my previous comment: the effect will only run on mount and leaving it out does not cause the linter to detect missing dependency because the linter knows it won't change.